# Sql: Merge rows with same id and multiple attributes

Tags: sql, merge, rows

I have a SQL table that looks like this:

```
Name | Attributes
-----------------
Toto | Attr1
Toto | Attr2
Titi | Attr1
```

and I would like a SQL request to merge the rows with attributes "Attr1" AND "Attr2" to have this table:

```
Name
----
Toto
```

How can I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `names` that have both attributes, you can use `group by`:

```
select name
from t
where attributes in ('Attr1', 'Att2')
group by name
having count(distinct attributes) = 2;
```